# Filtering table based on the latest row condition

Tags: r, dplyr, filter, filtering, subset

I have a table like the following:

```
date  user  X1 X2 X3
1/1     1    0  3 34 
2/1     1    0  7 65
3/1     1    0  0  0
4/1     1   25  4 65
1/1     2  285  0  0
2/1     2    0  0  0
3/1     2    0 54  0
4/1     2    0  0  0
```

How can I use `dplyr` to select the users that have non-zero data only at the last available date (4/1) for all Xs ?? In this case `user 2` should be removed. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option using `any` with `c_across` to check if the values are 0 and the last `row_number` like this:

```r
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(user) %>%
  filter(any(c_across(starts_with("X")) != 0 & row_number() == n()))
#> # A tibble: 4 × 5
#> # Groups:   user [1]
#>   date   user    X1    X2    X3
#>   <chr> <int> <int> <int> <int>
#> 1 1/1       1     0     3    34
#> 2 2/1       1     0     7    65
#> 3 3/1       1     0     0     0
#> 4 4/1       1    25     4    65
```

<sup>Created on 2023-03-15 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 4):

With `if_any` to keep a group if any of the selected column in the last row for a group has a value different from 0:

```r
library(dplyr) #1.1.0+
df %>%
  filter(if_any(X1:X3, ~ .x[n()] != 0), .by = user)

#   date user X1 X2 X3
# 1  1/1    1  0  3 34
# 2  2/1    1  0  7 65
# 3  3/1    1  0  0  0
# 4  4/1    1 25  4 65
```

Comment: Close but not correct. If you add a non-zero value for `user 2` at `4/1` for any `X`, then code will still drop `user 2`, while we would not like to.

Comment: @Telis Maybe try `df %>% filter(!if_all(X1:X3, ~ .x[n()] == 0), .by = user)` ?

Comment: Use `if_any` instead

Answer (score 2):

With `dplyr`, we can calculate the `rowSums` of the `last` record.

```r
library(dplyr)

# or across(X1:X3, last) if you only have positive values
df %>% filter(rowSums(across(X1:X3, ~last(abs(.x)))) != 0, .by = user)

  date user X1 X2 X3
1  1/1    1  0  3 34
2  2/1    1  0  7 65
3  3/1    1  0  0  0
4  4/1    1 25  4 65
```

Comment: What if sum gives you zero? 2+1-3

Comment: @zx8754 Good point! I just updated the code to wrap the `last` value with `abs`.

Answer (score 0):

Although the OP clearly prefers `dplyr` for completeness a `data.table` solution

```
library(data.table)

setDT(df)

df[, .SD[any(.SD[.N, X1:X3] != 0)], user]

   user date X1 X2 X3
1:    1  1/1  0  3 34
2:    1  2/1  0  7 65
3:    1  3/1  0  0  0
4:    1  4/1 25  4 65
```